# NiFi Avro schema: Copying value into another parameter

Tags: apache-nifi, avro

I'm using simple NiFi process to transfer data from Postgres to Oracle database.
The trigger of process is new record in my Postgres dictionary object, where I got two keys, KeyA and KeyB.
When new record appears, I'm splitting it and converting to json, after this I run GenerateTableFetch with "`where transfertype = ${KeyA}`" and then executeSQL Records to provide data into PutDatabaseRecord processor.
*Im transferring several sources to several destination with one flow (I have $.destination_object and $.desctination_db) so in source and destination for one type of data is the same structure.*

Now I have a problem with PutDatabaseRecord, in Oracle KeyB is mandatory and I want to copy my KeyA always in KeyB column, in data which is generated by ExecuteSQLRecord.

here is the flow, any ideas?

[image]

for more details, here is the process flow, and I want to replace B in Generated Data with Y

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue with UpdateRecord processor adding /NewValue & /OldValue in its path and passed my parameters in it and it solved my problem.